# Error en DataTable "Requested unknown parameter '3' for row 20."

Tags: html, html-tabla

se me ha presentado este error y no he podido solucionarlo, espero puedan ayudarme:

Este es mi código de HTML:

```
<table id="example-datatable" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>
<td style="width: 3%;">Curso</td>
<td style="width: 25%;">Dirigente</td>
<td style="width: 25%;">Horario</td>
<td style="width: 25%;">&Aacute;rea</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Inicial II Subnivel I A</td>
<td>Miss María Belen Salazar</td>
<td>Lunes y Martes 07h15 - 07h45</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Inicial II Subnivel I B</td>
<td>Miss Ariana Araujo</td>
<td>Jueves 07h15 - 08h15</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Inicial II Subnivel I C</td>
<td>Miss Andrea Silva</td>
<td>Martes y Jueves 07h15 - 07h45</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Inicial II Subnivel II A</td>
<td>Miss Lady Padilla</td>
<td>Martes y Miércoles 07h15 - 07h45</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Inicial II Subnivel II B</td>
<td>Miss Clara González </td>  
<td>Martes y Viernes 07h15 - 07h45</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Inicial II Subnivel II C</td>
<td>Miss María Quintero</td>
<td>Martes y Viernes 07h15 - 07h45</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Inicial II Subnivel II D</td>
<td>Miss Stephanie Cantos</td>
<td>Lunes y Jueves 08h00 - 08h30</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Preparatoria A</td>
<td>Miss Alexandra Mocha</td>
<td>Lunes 08h50 - 09h30</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Preparatoria B</td>
<td>Miss Mariuxi Peñafiel</td>
<td>Miércoles 07h30 - 08h10</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Preparatoria C</td>
<td>Miss Kellin Cepeda</td>
<td>Jueves 07h30 - 08h10</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Preparatoria D</td>
<td>Miss Sabrina Fierro</td>
<td>Miércoles 08h10 - 08h50</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Preparatoria E</td>
<td>Miss Estefanía Gómez</td>
<td>Jueves 08h10 - 08h50</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Segundo A</td>
<td>Miss Marjorie Gómez</td>
<td>Miércoles 07h40 - 08h20</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Segundo B</td>
<td>Miss Analía Ruiz</td>
<td>Jueves 07h40 - 08h20</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Segundo C</td>
<td>Miss Debora España</td>
<td>Martes 07h30 - 08h10</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
<td>Segundo D</td>
<td>Miss Sucetty Ramos</td>
<td>Lunes 08h10 - 08h50</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Tercero A</td>
<td>Miss Pamela Vera</td>
<td>Miércoles 08h10 - 08h50</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Tercero B</td>
<td>Miss Sandra Arias</td>
<td>Jueves 08h10 - 08h50</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
<td>Tercero C</td>
<td>Miss Paola Lavayen</td>
<td>Martes 07h30 - 08h10</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Tercero D</td>
<td>Miss Rosemary Llamuca</td>
<td>Lunes 08h10 - 08h50</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Cuarto A</td>
<td>Miss María Teresa Benites</td>
<td>Jueves 08h10 - 08h50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Cuarto B</td>
<td>Miss Karla Lojan</td>
<td>Lunes 08h10 - 08h50</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Cuarto C</td>
<td>Miss Jessica Merchán</td>
<td>Viernes 08h10 - 08h50</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Cuarto D</td>
<td>Miss Narcisa Jiménez</td>
<td>Miércoles 08h10 - 08h50</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Quinto A</td>
<td>Miss Cintya Núñez</td>
<td>Lunes 08h50 - 09h30</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Quinto B</td>
<td>Miss Geovanna Baquerizo</td>
<td>Martes 08h10 - 08h50</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Sexto A</td>
<td>Miss Andrea Chavez </td>
<td>Lunes 08h10 - 08h50</td>
<td>Aprende a Pensar (8vo - 9no), Lengua y Literatura (7mo - 8vo)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Sexto B</td>
<td>Miss Francisca Ruales</td>
<td>Jueves 07h30 - 08h10</td>
<td>Lengua y Literatura (6to)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>S&eacute;ptimo A</td>
<td>Miss Melanie Layana</td>
<td>Lunes 08h10 - 08h50</td>
<td>Estudios Sociales (6to a 8vo),Contabilidad(8vo a 10mo), 
Emprendimiento y gestión(1ro bachillerato)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>S&eacute;ptimo B</td>
<td>Miss Cintya Márquez</td>
<td>Jueves 08h10 - 08h50</td>
<td>Matemáticas (6to a 7mo)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Octavo</td>
<td>Miss Laura Monserrate</td>
<td>Viernes 08h10 - 08h50</td>
<td>Matemáticas (8vo a 9no), Aprende a Pensar (10mo a 1ro de bachillerato)</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
<td>Noveno</td>
<td>Miss María España</td>
<td>Miércoles 08h10 - 08h50</td>
<td>Lengua y Literatura (9no a 1ro de bachillerato)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Décimo</td>
<td>Miss Pilar Moran</td>
<td>Martes 08h10 - 08h50</td>
<td>Estudios Sociales(9no a 10mo), Historia(1ro de bachillerato), 
Informática(1ro de bachillerato), Educación a la ciudadanía (1ro de bachillerato), 
Filosofía(1ro de bachillerato)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Primero de Bachillerato</td>
<td>Mr. Victor Patiño</td>
<td>Martes 08h10 - 08h50</td>
<td>Matemáticas(10mo a 1ro de bachillerato), Física(1ro de bachillerato)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Profesor de Área</td>
<td>Mr. Juli&aacute;n Gonzalez</td>
<td>Viernes 07h30 - 08h10</td>
<td>Educación Cultural y Artística (Preparatoria a 1ro de bachillerato)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Profesor de Área</td>
<td>Miss Paula Bonilla</td>
<td>Martes 08h00 - 08h50</td>
<td>Formaci&oacute;n Cristiana (Preparatoria a 7mo), Aprende a Pensar (5to)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Profesor de Área</td>
<td>Mr. Elvis Fariño</td>
<td>Lunes y Jueves 08h10 - 08h50</td>
<td>Educaci&oacute;n F&iacute;sica (1ro a 3ro A-B)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Profesor de Área</td>
<td>Miss Katty Mac&iacute;as</td>
<td>Martes 07h30 - 08h10</td>
<td>Educaci&oacute;n F&iacute;sica (3ro C a 1ro de bachillerato)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Profesor de Área</td>
<td>Miss Fanest Coronado</td>
<td>Viernes 08h10 - 08h50</td>
<td>Inglés (3ro D - 4to C)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Profesor de Área</td>
<td>Miss María Isabel Ampuero</td>
<td>Martes 07h30 - 08h10</td>
<td>Language Arts (Preparatoria A-D), Aprende a pensar (7mo) </td>
</tr>
 <tr>
<td>Profesor de Área</td>
<td>Mr. Nelson Delgado</td>
<td>Lunes 08h10 - 08h50</td>
<td>Inglés (4to D a 6to A) </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Profesor de Área</td>
<td>Miss Betty Vega</td>
<td>Miércoles y Jueves 07h15 - 07h45</td>
<td>Language Arts (Inicial II Sub. II A - D)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Profesor de Area</td>
<td>Miss Rebeca Durand</td>
<td>Miércoles 07h30 - 08h10</td>
<td>Música (Preparatoria a 7mo)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Profesor de Area</td>
<td>Mr.Danny González</td>
<td>Viernes 07h30 - 08h10</td>
<td>Inglés (2do D a 4ro C), Aprende a pensar (6to)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Profesor de Area</td>
<td>Miss Wendy Sánchez</td>
<td>Miércoles 08h10 - 08h50</td>
<td>Formación Cristiana(8vo a 1ro bachillerato), 
Informática (6to B a 10mo), Robótica (7mo a 10mo)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Profesor de Area</td>
<td>Miss Andrea Villafuerte</td>
<td>Martes y Viernes 08h10 - 08h50</td>
<td>Inglés (Preparatoria E a 2do C)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Profesor de Area</td>
<td>Miss Katherine Villegas</td>
<td>Jueves 08h10 - 08h50</td>
<td>Ciencias Naturales (6to a 7mo)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Profesor de Area</td>
<td>Mr. Iván Lucín</td>
<td>Viernes 07h30 - 08h10</td>
<td>Robótica (2do a 6to)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Profesor de Area</td>
<td>Mr. Ercik Tomalá</td>
<td>Lunes 07h30 - 08h10</td>
<td>Informática (2do a 6to A)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Profesor de Area</td>
<td>Miss Samantha Ricaurte</td>
<td>Miércoles 07h15 - 07h45</td>
<td>Language Arts (Inicial II Sub. I), Aprender a pensar(4to)</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Código Js en index:

```
<script src="js/tablesDatatables.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(function(){ TablesDatatables.init(); });
</script>
```

Codigo JS:

```
var TablesDatatables = function() {

    return {
        init: function() {
            /* Initialize Bootstrap Datatables Integration */
            App.datatables();

            /* Initialize Datatables */
            $('#example-datatable').dataTable({
                //"aoColumnDefs": [ { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 1, 5 ] } ],
                "iDisplayLength": 1,
                "aLengthMenu": [[1], [1, 20, 30, "All"]],
                "bInfo":false,
                "bSort": false
            });

            /* Add placeholder attribute to the search input */
            $('.dataTables_filter input').attr('placeholder', 'Ingresar los apellidos');
        }
    };
}();
```

Al eliminar el `<thead>...</thead>` de la tabla, no muestra el error pero me muestra toda la tabla, sin reducir la tabla.

Espero me puedan ayudar, quedo muy agradecido por su tiempo y conocimiento,
Gracias.

Comment: Enseñanos también el codigo JS que usas, si no sera dificil ayudarte.

Comment: Buenas tardes, ya agregue lo que faltaba, gracias por responder. @FranciscoGarrido

Comment: No se si esto que tienes  funciona `"aLengthMenu": [[1], [1, 20, 30, "All"]],`; podrías intentar colocar esto: `lengthMenu: [[1, 20, 30, -1], [1, 20, 30, "All"]],` indica la longitud del menú y este otro indica la cantidad inicial `pageLength: 1,`

Comment: Otra cosa no es necesario colocar `&nbsp;` dentro de los `td` que están vacíos `<td>&nbsp;</td>` puede colocar esto `<td></td>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes una fila de la tabla con solo 3 celdas, está descuadrando la tabla y dandote el error.

```
<tr>
<td>Cuarto A</td>
<td>Miss María Teresa Benites</td>
<td>Jueves 08h10 - 08h50</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Si en definitiva este es un error, dejar dentro de un `tr` sin un `td`

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus respuestas, corregiré lo indicado.